# Scanning strings and ints from file into array in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, int, scanf

I am scanning from a file into parallel arrays.
I successfully scan the strings, but the ints and floats do not scan correctly! 
What is going wrong here???
Num, human, and cool are arrays declared in the main function.

An example of a record in hello.txt:
`Angela, Merkel, 50, 10, 9.1`

```
void read(int *lines, char first[ENTRY][FIRST], char last[ENTRY][LAST], int *num, int *human, float *cool)
{
FILE *ifile;
int i;

ifile = fopen("hello.txt", "r");

fscanf(ifile, "%[^,] %*c %[^,] %*c %d %*c %d %*c %f", first[0], last[0], &num[0], &human[0], &cool[0]);

printf("%s", first[0]);
printf("%s\n", last[0]);
printf("%d\n", num[0]);
printf("%d\n", human[0]);
printf("%f", cool[0]);



fclose(ifile);
}
```

Comment: First, check the return value of `fscanf()`...

Comment: Show `hello.txt` , definition variable and how to call this.

Comment: @user9012 can you please post the full question here? without that we cant help much

Comment: Presented code looks like  no problem. variables or how variables pass to function  has a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
fscanf(ifile, "%[^,] %*c %[^,] %*c %d %*c %d %*c %f", first[0], last[0], num, human, cool);
```

Comment: But num, human, cool are arrays declared in the main function.

Comment: It does not matter. You pass them to your `read` as pointers and this is all that `fscanf` needs. It would be more complex if you read several numbers into any of those arrays.

Answer (score 0):

First, with `scanf` family of functions, a space matches any amount of white space, including none, in the input, also don't use `%*c`, it is not necessary. Second, you need to specify the comma in format string to successfully scan the fields. Third, when you `scanf` always check its return value to make sure the expected number fields were input. Try this fix:

```
void read(int *lines, char first[ENTRY][FIRST], char last[ENTRY][LAST], int *num, int *human, float *cool)
{
    FILE *ifile;

    ifile = fopen("hello.txt", "r");
    if (ifile == NULL) return;

    int ret = fscanf(ifile, "%[^,], %[^,], %d, %d, %f", first[0], last[0], &num[0], &human[0], &cool[0]);
    if (ret != 5) { // input file does not match the format
        return;
    }

    printf("%s ", first[0]);
    printf("%s\n", last[0]);
    printf("%d\n", num[0]);
    printf("%d\n", human[0]);
    printf("%f\n", cool[0]);

    fclose(ifile);
}
```